# Find GCD queue info and which thread a queue lives from the executing block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

When a block added to a queue is executed, is it possible to find out the queue info (such as if it is main queue, concurrent queue, etc.) and which thread the queue lives in?

Answer (score 0):

Even through it's deprecated in iOS6, you can still use [dispatch_get_current_queue()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_current_queue) for debugging purposes. Then you can get main queue with dispatch_get_main_queue() and global queues with dispatch_get_global_queue() and check which one of them is equal to your queue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly compare queues in GCD.  Please see this answer: [Is this the right way to compare two GCD Queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489098/is-this-the-right-way-to-compare-two-gcd-queues/17507605#17507605)

If you only need to check if you are on the main thread (for interacting with UIKit for example), then use `[NSThread isMainThread]` or `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)`.