# Calling delegate methods either synchronously or asynchronously on a user provided queue

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an API with its own delegate. I provide the caller a property to chose their own callback queue for the delegate methods.

The structure of my API class looks like:

```
class MyAPI {
  weak var delegate: APIDelegate!
  let delegateDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue

  init(delegate: APIDelegate, delegateDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.delegateDispatchQueue = delegateDispatchQueue
  }

  // public method definitions ... 
}
```

While mostly I can call the delegate methods asynchronously, in some cases I need to call them synchronously. And that's where I seem to run into problems. If the user of my API calls my methods on the main thread, and they give the `delegateDispatchQueue` as the main queue, I get a crash when I try to call delegate methods synchronously.

Here is the helper class I'm using to dispatch my delegate calls to hopefully add a bit more flesh to this issue:

```
// Calls SyncServerDelegate methods on the `delegateDispatchQueue` either synchronously or asynchronously.
class Delegator {
    private weak var delegate: SyncServerDelegate!
    private let delegateDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue
    
    init(delegate: SyncServerDelegate, delegateDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.delegateDispatchQueue = delegateDispatchQueue
    }
    
    // All delegate methods must be called using this, to have them called on the client requested DispatchQueue. If sync is true, delegate method is effectively called synchronously on the `delegateDispatchQueue`. If sync is false, delegate method is called asynchronously on the `delegateDispatchQueue`.
    func call(sync: Bool = false, callback: @escaping (SyncServerDelegate)->()) {
        if sync {
            // This is crashing with: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
            // seemingly because I am doing a sync dispatch on the main thread when I'm already on the main thread. The problem is, I can't compare threads/queues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489098

            delegateDispatchQueue.sync { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                callback(self.delegate)
            }
        }
        else {
            delegateDispatchQueue.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                callback(self.delegate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My initial thought on a solution was to internally dispatch methods to another queue. Such as:

```
class MyAPI {
  // ...
 private let startQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SyncServer", qos: .background)

  public myAPIMethod() throws {
     startQueue.async {
       try myAPIMethodAux() // syntax error
     }
  }
}
```

but this is currently a non-starter because I am doing error handling in much of my code by throwing errors and the above pattern immediately generates a syntax error. I could re-write code without this form of error handling, but that's a big effort I'm not quite ready to take on.

Thoughts?

---

## Update

I've not solved this yet, but am working around it. I've split my delegate methods into two parts. The main group of them I can call back asynchronously  on `delegateDispatchQueue`. The other group, where I need to call them synchronously, I make no promises about what queue I call them on-- and just use the same queue that my API is currently running on.

Comment: I'm surprised it's crashing rather than deadlocking.  (If that's the real reason, I suppose it's better than the old behavior.)  Do you get any other messages in the debug console at the time of the crash?

Comment: I was surprised about that myself. No other messages. I've moved on now with a workaround though. So, not easy to repeat right now.